# Set LPSTR from CString

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip, cstring

I am trying to set tooltips on an MFC dialog. I have the code for reading the tooltips from a string resource and am trying to modify it to not read from the resource and instead make up a tooltip.

My implementation is causing garbage to be displayed as the tooltip instead of teh string I want to. Also, it is causing a crash when run from the debugger but not when the executable is run directly (I am sure there is a buffer corruption or something similar)

Here is the code which is relevant:

```
BOOL CPreviewDlg::OnToolTipText(UINT, NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    ASSERT(pNMHDR->code == TTN_NEEDTEXT);

    TOOLTIPTEXT* pTTT = (TOOLTIPTEXT*)pNMHDR;

    if (!(pTTT->uFlags & TTF_IDISHWND))
        return FALSE;

    UINT_PTR hWnd = pNMHDR->idFrom;
    // idFrom is actually the HWND of the tool
    UINT nID = (UINT)(WORD)::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)hWnd);

    CString sDlgItemText;
    (UINT)(WORD)::GetDlgItemText(this->GetSafeHwnd(), nID, sDlgItemText.GetBufferSetLength(50), 50);
    sDlgItemText.ReleaseBuffer();

    if(sDlgItemText.IsEmpty())
        sDlgItemText = _T("Unnamed");

    CString sToolTip = _T("");
    sToolTip.Format(_T("%s \n This is the %s control. Here we can put its description."), sDlgItemText, sDlgItemText);

    pTTT->lpszText = sToolTip.GetBufferSetLength(sToolTip.GetLength());/* MAKEINTRESOURCE(nID);*/
    pTTT->hinst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
    sToolTip.ReleaseBuffer();
    *pResult = 0;

    // bring the tooltip window above other popup windows
    ::SetWindowPos(pNMHDR->hwndFrom, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);

    return TRUE;    // message was handled
}
```

I am pretty sure the error is where I am trying to set the `pTTT->lpszText` (instead of MAKEINTRESOURCE) I think I am not getting the correct way of setting a LPSTR from a CString

```
CString sDlgItemText;
(UINT)(WORD)::GetDlgItemText(this->GetSafeHwnd(), nID, sDlgItemText.GetBufferSetLength(50), 50);
sDlgItemText.ReleaseBuffer();

if(sDlgItemText.IsEmpty())
    sDlgItemText = _T("Unnamed");

CString sToolTip = _T("");
sToolTip.Format(_T("%s \n This is the %s control. Here we can put its description."), sDlgItemText, sDlgItemText);

pTTT->lpszText = sToolTip.GetBufferSetLength(sToolTip.GetLength());/* MAKEINTRESOURCE(nID);*/
```

Comment: The lpszText in a TOOLTIPTEXT is an LPTSTR, not an LPSTR, so that would have to be compatible with a CString. (CString is either 8 bits of 16 bits depending on your project settings, and so is LPTSTR.) So the error must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem is that you are returning the address of a local variable (`sToolTip.m_pData)` from your `OnToolTipText` handler. When control leaves the notification handler, `sToolTip` goes out of scope and its destructor is run, leaving behind garbage.

To solve the issue you have 2 options:

1. Copy the tooltip text to the `TOOLTIPTEXT::szText[]` array.
2. Increase the lifetime of the buffer you return so that it is available when the system needs it. The lifetime doesn't need to be any longer than the enclosing entity (the dialog in this case), so a class member of the dialog will do.

Unrelated to your question: When assigning a pointer to `TOOLTIPTEXT::lpszText` member you should be using a `const_cast` instead of calling `CString::GetBuffer[SetLength]()`. The `TOOLTIPTEXT` structure is used in both directions, to set and retrieve tooltip information. Consequently, the members cannot be declared `const`, even if they are. It may look awkward but you would rather want to do the following:

```
pTTT->lpszText = const_cast<LPTSTR>(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(sToolTip));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the pointer value in `pTTT->lpszText` is not valid any more once you exit the function.

If your text is less than 80 characters long, or if you can afford to truncate the tooltip, you can use

```
lstrcpy(pTTT->szText, sToolTip);
```

Otherwise, you will need to make `sToolTip` either a global variable or a member variable of the `CPreviewDlg` class.

Reference: [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4sc5ex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).